# AWS EC2 Instance Store: What IOPS do these have?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Looking at the EC2 instance types (https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ ) I don't see any concrete values for IOPS.

I do see values for EBS volumes (https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/features/ ).

Is there any more information out there as to what you can expect IOPS-wise from an EC2 instance store?

Comment: I suspect (so not an answer) that the actual hardware attached to the instance varies too much for them to make an official pronouncement. It also may not be regulated at the hypervisor level, meaning that your performance will depend on the other VMs sharing the physical hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found this for `i3` instances:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage-optimized-instances.html#i2-instances-diskperf

but nothing for other instance types.

Answer (score 0):

IOPS and Throughput details:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage-optimized-instances.html

Throughput is given for D+I types, IOPS is only given for I types.
But i believe here we have the highest  numbers.
IOPS: 3,300,000 (Read)  1,760,000 (Write)
Throughput: Baseline (12.5 GBps) Burst (25 GBps)

What type of Storage Media is available:
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#instance-store-volumes